# Breadcrumb links not working correctly

Tags: php, function, breadcrumbs

Well I have this code -

```
function breadcrumbs($separator = ' &raquo; ', $home = 'Home') {
    $path = array_filter(explode('/', parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH)));
    $base = ($_SERVER['HTTPS'] ? 'https' : 'http') . '://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/';
    $breadcrumbs = Array("<a href=\"$base\">$home</a>");
    foreach ($path AS $x => $crumb) {
        $title = ucwords(str_replace(Array('.php', '_', '-'), Array('', ' ', ' '), $crumb));
        $breadcrumbs[] = "<a href=\"$base$crumb\">$title</a>";  
    }
    return implode($separator, $breadcrumbs);
}
```

And lets say I am at the page url of:

`http://www.mysite.com/forums/general/log-book`

this function displays the breadcrumb correctly as `Home » Forums » General » Log Book`.

However, when I click on one of the breadcrumb links it only goes back to the basic site url structure - such as "General" goes back to `http://www.mysite.com/general` when it actually should go to

`http://www.mysite.com/forums/general`

How do you guys suggest I go about fixing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
function breadcrumbs($separator = ' &raquo; ', $home = 'Home') {
    $path = array_filter(explode('/', parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH)));
    $base = ($_SERVER['HTTPS'] ? 'https' : 'http') . '://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/';
    $breadcrumbs = Array("<a href=\"$base\">$home</a>");
    foreach ($path AS $x => $crumb) {
        $title = ucwords(str_replace(Array('.php', '_', '-'), Array('', ' ', ' '), $crumb));
        $breadcrumbs[] = "<a href=\"$base$crumb\">$title</a>";  
        $base = $base.$crumb.'/';
    }
    return implode($separator, $breadcrumbs);
}
```

Note the changed line `$base = $base.$crumb.'/';`

Comment: Brilliant mate! Never even thought of looking at it in that sense. Thank you very much.

Comment: agree, but you could put the $base = $base.$crumb.'/'; above the $breadcrumbs[] = "<a href=\"$base$crumb\">$title</a>"; and just make it $breadcrumbs[] = "<a href=\"$base\">$title</a>"; instead, and the $base = $base.$crumb.'/'; could just be $base .= $crumb.'/';

Comment: yes, that would also work (the cleaner the code the better! ha)

Answer (score 1):

Given your `$path` array looks like:

```
array(
   'forums',
   'general',
   'log-book'
)
```

You might traverse it backwards:

```
while (NULL !== ($crumb = array_shift($path))) {
   $title = ucwords(str_replace(Array('.php', '_', '-'), Array('', ' ', ' '), $crumb));
   $url = implode('/', $path) . '/' . $crumb;
   $breadcrumbs[] = "<a href=\"$base$crumb\">$title</a>";
}
```

Note 1: Don't rely on `HTTP_HOST`. Use `SERVER_NAME` instead. The former can be forged using the HTTP request's `Host: ...` field.

Note 2: I'm a fan of Yoda conditionals.